# How to calculate the width of the box with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do calculate the width from the initial box to the box we will click on?

So if I click the yellow button.. Then width of the red, blue, green, yellow boxes will be calculated

200 + 150 + 180 + 120, result is 650px

[image]

And if I click the green box, the result will be 530px

[image]

If you click the red box, just width of the red box (200px)

https://jsfiddle.net/wx05ng24/

```js
$('.div-click').click(function(e){
  $(this).outerWidth();
  alert($(this).outerWidth());
});
```

```css
 .centerDiv
 {
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .div-click
 {
  height:200px;
  float:left;
 }
 .A
 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color:#fe0000 ;
 }
 .B
 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color:#0036fe ;
 }
 .C
 {
  width: 180px;
  background-color:#00fe36 ;
 }
 .D
 {
  width: 120px;
  background-color:#fecb00 ;
 }
 .E
 {
  width: 130px;
  background-color:#fe00e3 ;
 }
 .F
 {
  width: 140px;
  background-color:#5a4c54 ;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="centerDiv">
  <div class="div-click A">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click B">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click C">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click D">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click E">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click F">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: the question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prevAll()](https://api.jquery.com/prevall/) to get each preceding div and add their width to the total like this:

```js
$('.div-click').click(function(e) {
  var totWidth = this.offsetWidth;
  $(this).prevAll().each(function(index) {
    totWidth += this.offsetWidth
  });
  console.log(totWidth);
});
```

```css
.centerDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.div-click {
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.A {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fe0000;
}

.B {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #0036fe;
}

.C {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #00fe36;
}

.D {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #fecb00;
}

.E {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fe00e3;
}

.F {
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #5a4c54;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="centerDiv">
  <div class="div-click A">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click B">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click C">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click D">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click E">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click F">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, this is practical. because before I used length to take one by one the width of the box. Once again, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `prevAll('.div-click')` to get all the previous elment of the clicked element.

```js
   

$('.div-click').click(function(e) {
      var $prev = $(this).prevAll('.div-click');
      var width = $(this).width();;
      $.each($prev, function() {
        width += $(this).width();
      });
      alert("total width: " + width);
   });
```

```css
.centerDiv
 {
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .div-click
 {
  height:200px;
  float:left;
 }
 .A
 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color:#fe0000 ;
 }
 .B
 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color:#0036fe ;
 }
 .C
 {
  width: 180px;
  background-color:#00fe36 ;
 }
 .D
 {
  width: 120px;
  background-color:#fecb00 ;
 }
 .E
 {
  width: 130px;
  background-color:#fe00e3 ;
 }
 .F
 {
  width: 140px;
  background-color:#5a4c54 ;
 }
```

```html
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="centerDiv">
  <div class="div-click A">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click B">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click C">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click D">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click E">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click F">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the position of the element and then add its width:

`$(this).position().left + $(this).outerWidth()`

Note that you have to make the containing div `position: relative;`.
And it will only work if the divs are next to each other and aren't breaking to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy just keep track of the selected div.

So if we select div 3 then we need to calculate 1,2 and 3. for this i used `.index()`

Se the example below to understand more

```js
$(".centerDiv> div").click(function(){
console.clear();
var index = $(this).index() // know the index of the div which selected
var widthSum =0;
var sumText = "";
$(this).parent().children("div").each(function(itemIndex, item){
   
     if (itemIndex <= index) // Keep track of the divs we want to calculate
     {
         widthSum += $(item).width();
         sumText += $(item).attr("class").split(" ")[1] + " "; // just to show which div did we included
      }
         
     

  });
  
  console.log("The total width of divs ["+ sumText+ "] is " + widthSum)
});
```

```css
 .centerDiv
 {
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .div-click
 {
  height:200px;
  float:left;
 }
 .A
 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color:#fe0000 ;
 }
 .B
 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color:#0036fe ;
 }
 .C
 {
  width: 180px;
  background-color:#00fe36 ;
 }
 .D
 {
  width: 120px;
  background-color:#fecb00 ;
 }
 .E
 {
  width: 130px;
  background-color:#fe00e3 ;
 }
 .F
 {
  width: 140px;
  background-color:#5a4c54 ;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="centerDiv">
  <div class="div-click A">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click B">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click C">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click D">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click E">
  </div>
  <div class="div-click F">
  </div>
 </div>
```